# I am not able to install scikit-image package from anaconda

Tags: python-3.x

conda install scikit-image
I used this command in anaconda prompt to install this library but I am getting an error

[image]

I have set the environment variable as my jupyter notbook is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the anaconda prompt. Go to the Windows start icon, start typing "Anaconda", select "Anaconda prompt". A new command window opens. Now you can use conda from there.

Comment: @Apurva Agarwal did this work?  If it did, please upvote/accept the answer so future readers will know that someone tried this answer and it worked, thanks :)